# Is there a direct comparison between Lucene.Net syntax and Amazon Cloud Search syntax

Tags: lucene.net, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a large application that has hundreds of lines of complex queries in lucene.net, and I want to be able to move to Amazon Cloud Search.

Instead of re-writing all the queries, I was thinking of writing some sort of converter.  Before I do though, I thought I would make sure that there is a direct comparison for every type of Lucene Query?  Things like inner clauses etc.

Better yet, is there already a library that does it?

I aware that there is a .net library for query cloud search, and also the aws sdk, but I want to have something that allows easy switching between local lucene.net and ACS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's way easier than that -- just select CloudSearch's Lucene query parser via the parameter `q.parser=lucene` with your queries. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching.html

> lucene—specify search criteria using the Apache Lucene query parser
>   syntax. If you currently use the Lucene syntax, using the lucene query
>   parser enables you to migrate your search services to an Amazon
>   CloudSearch domain without having to completely rewrite your search
>   queries in the Amazon CloudSearch structured search syntax.

Comment: I just re-read your question and realized you said lucene*.net* rather than just lucene. I'm not familiar with that, so sorry if this answer is not helpful afterall.

Comment: That is awesome information.  it looks like it's the missing piece I needed.  I just need to know if there is anything that ACS doesn't support.  I look separately into whether you can interchange between lucene.net syntax and other solutions.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it and thanks for reporting back.